# Generic wildcard bounderies in complex types

Tags: java, generics

I don't understand [generic wildcard bounderies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) ussage.
Could you please explain why `processList` works pretty well while `processMap` fails with compilation error in the following example? How should I change signature of `processMap` to make it work with both `Map<String, List<String>>` and `Map<String, List<Object>>`

```
public void processList(List<? extends Object> list) {
}

public void processMap(Map<String, List<? extends Object>> map) {
}

public void f() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    processList(list); // OK
    processMap(map); // ERROR
}
```

---

While moving generic type definition from method argument type to method paramether made the trick

```
public void processMap(Map<String, List<? extends Object>> map)
public <T extends Object> void processMap(Map<String, List<T>> map)
```

I would now like to know difference between the two. Moved to [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568756/two-ways-of-java-generic-method-declaration).

Comment: I dont know if I am right or not, but it seems like java compiler is not able resolve or convert the collection type being used as the key to Map collection defined in the problem. I am saying this because when I modify the function signature as `public static <T extends Object> void  processMap(Map<? extends Object, List<T>> map)`, it works fine. Seems like there is a great difference between `<T extends Object>` and `<? extends Object>` when used in such declarations. Its multi-level wildcards concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work if you eliminate the wildcard. I.e. you create a generic function with a named type: `<T extends Object>`

```
public <T extends Object> void processMap(Map<String, List<T>> map) {
}

public void processList(List<? extends Object> list) {
}

public void f() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    processList(list); // OK
    processMap(map); // OK now
    processMap(new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>()); // this is OK too
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't explain why the function with the wildcard doesn't work.

Comment: I think the reason _why_ this works has something to do with [wildcard capture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html).

Comment: Just posted the same ... only difference: there is no need to put the `extends Object` there. Any T that you ever will be using will be extending Object without you telling the compiler ;-)

Comment: Yeah. Using `<T>` is okay now. the `extends` is good for stuff like `<T extends CharSequence>`

Answer (score 1):

Half an answer: the following code does compile for me.

Missing: a good explanation for why a named T works; but an unnamed ? does not.

```
public <T> void processMap(Map<String, List<T>> map) {
}

public void f() {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    processMap(map);
    Map<String, List<Object>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    processMap(map2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, List<? extends Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

make the above change in f() method and it work.
Java compiler check the type of variable so both should be same, i may wrong.